# Redirect attemtp with javascript in Django template - produces invalid url

Tags: javascript, python, django, redirect

I've got a very simple Django template (and I'm a total noob with frontends though) where I want to do a javascript redirect after IP address of the server changes.

This is actually part of a server configuration site, that allows changing it's IP (as on e.g. routers admin web consoles).

Page displays information to the user that server will reboot and in the meantime server asynchronously initializes the reboot sequence. After some delay, a trivial javascript oneliner tries to reconnect server on new IP address.

In this example im trying to change IP from: 192.168.1.31 to: 192.168.1.41 but after page with information is shown:

```
# Server is now rebooting. If page doesn't open within 30 seconds, please refresh it with F5 button.
# Redirecting to: 192.168.1.41:8080/config
```

... I'm getting to following error page:

```
# Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request URL:       
# http://192.168.1.31:8080/config/192.168.1.41:8080/config
# 
# Using the URLconf defined in cfgviewer.urls, Django tried these URL
# patterns, in this order:
# 
#     ^config/ ^$ [name='index']
#     ^admin/
# 
# The current URL, config/192.168.1.41:8080/config, didn't match any of
# these.
#
# You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django
# settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
# standard 404 page.
```

Main page **index.html** redirects to **reboot.html** when IP address changes and is passing `redirect_address` to it in POST request.

Snippet form **index.html**:

```
(...)
context = {
(...)
   'redirect_address': redirect_address,
}

return render(request, 'cfgpanel/reboot.html', context)
(...)
```

Django **reboot.html** template code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Server Configuration - rebooting...</title>
    </head>
<body>

<h1>Server is now rebooting. If page doesn't open within 30 seconds, please refresh it with F5 button.</h1>

{% if redirect_address != "" %}
<div>
    <h3 class="error_msg">Redirecting to: {{ redirect_address }}:8080/config</h3>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var new_url = "{{ redirect_address }}:8080/config";
        window.location.replace(new_url)
    }, 30000);

    </script>
</div>
{% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

Django **urls.py** code:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = "config"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**Question:** Why the client/browser is not trying to reach absolute address I'm passing to it? How to make it opening `192.168.1.41:8080/config` instead of `http://192.168.1.31:8080/config/192.168.1.41:8080/config?`

Comment: did you try prepending `redirect_address` with "http://"?

Comment: No way! You know what? It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kendas suggested:

> prepending redirect_address with "http://"

did the job.